# Custom route in web api just redirects to current page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Being a noob in MVC web api  there is probably something very obvious I'm missing..

However, In my `ProjectController` I have the following method with attributes (*I know this kind of method should be POST but just testing easily...*):

```
[Route("api/projects/archive/{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]    
public void Archive(int id)
{
    _projectService.Archive(id);
}
```

However, when I open my URL such as:

```
http://localhost:49923/api/projects/archive/1
```

The page simply redirects to the current URL, and the archive method is not called. I also have a breakpoint at the method to verify it's not hit.

My best guess is I also have to update my web api route config which is the default, but I just assumed the route attribute was enough?

Here is my web api route config:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
        .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? :-)

**EDITS:**

Clearification 1 - my ProjectController:

```
public class ProjectsController : ApiController
{

    private ProjectService _projectService;

    public ProjectsController()
    {
        _projectService = new ProjectService();
    }

    [Route("api/projects/archive/{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]

    public void Archive(int id)
    {
        _projectService.Archive(id);
    }
}
```

Clearification 2 - redirect:

So lets say I stand on the homepage (/). I then go to the URL "`http://localhost:49923/api/projects/archive/1`", it will just reload page and leave my back at the home page.

Comment: clarify `The page simply redirects to the current URL, and the archive method is not called.` it is unclear. Also show the controller.

Comment: Read up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web API config is configured correctly.
Ensure that the controller and the action are constructed properly

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController {

    //...other code removed for brevity

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/projects/archive/{id:int}")]//Matches GET api/projects/archive/1
    public IHttpActionResult Archive(int id) {
        _projectService.Archive(id);
        return Ok();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its bit late to answer but hope you find it useful,

Many times the way how we write the code help us find the solution to the problem,
As Nkosi already answered, that the constructing controller and the action method properly will resolve the issue.

Its always helpful to check the method first rather then looking at the route.config because by default it will be the same unless you provide your custom attribute.